# Can't call child_process in Alexa Application

Tags: python, node.js

I have an Alexa Based lambda function where I am trying to have a graph generated when the python function is called.  The python module then uploads the generated graph to s3.  Both work fine on their own, however, when running in lambda, I get errors thrown when trying to use the child process to call they python module.  There is nothing returned from the process, and nothing in the node application uses anything from the python module.  Not sure what I have done wrong here...

```js
const PlotDataIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'PlotDataIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    let speechText  = ``;
    const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    //simple.py is just a hello world module, but even that won't run
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["./pythonModules/simple.py"]);
    speechText = "Successfully ran python module";
    return  handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(speechText)
    .getResponse();
  }

};
```